# XNA 4.0 Model into parts

Tags: xna, models

is there a way to split a .fbx model into parts, and move those parts individualy in XNA 4.0 ?

Thanks

Comment: I have no experience with such, but could you split the model into multiple ones beforehand and import them as different objects into XNA?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps when you draw each part you could give each one it's own world matrix, remembering that each part is still offset from the origin of the model as a whole.

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
{
    foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
    {
         ((BasicEffect)part.Effect).World = ((Matrix)part.Tag).worldMatrix;
         ((BasicEffect)part.Effect).View = viewMatrix;
         ((BasicEffect)part.Effect).Projection = projectionMatrix;
    }
    mesh.Draw();
}
```

Of course, this means that you'll need to find a way to identify each part and assign each of them their own special `worldMatrix`, because the `Tag` is always `null` by default.

Besides that, the only other solution that's immediately appent to me is to export the objects individually and treat them as their own entities.